# How to see who posted from my app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have a share button on my Android app that uses the new Android SDK.

From [this list](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) of parameters I am using `name, caption, description, link, picture`.

Everything is working okay, but I can't find a way to see who posted and mentioned my app on Facebook.

Can't find a way to add a hashtag `#` since `message` field is deprecated and hashtags come inside the post `message`.

Any idea ?

Comment: Try to implement "Analytics", so you can see how many people use it or which devices use it or even more...

Comment: @yahya I am already using analytics, but this seems like something very basic that needs to come from Facebook

Comment: You can send some count rate to your web server if not Analytics or wait for Facebook people to implement this thing.

Comment: You can use the "ref" parameter which allows you to categorize the type of shares and see them on insights. See the docs here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: @MingLi could be great, but I don't see it in any of the post fields here : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/